# How to pass a value with the same PHP file?

Tags: php

I want to pass the same boolean value "isProvena" several times in two PHP files. The first time I pass the value from utilitizer.php to hraprint.php by using the codes as follows:

```
if ($_POST['type'] == 'printphys' || $_POST['type'] == 'printprovenahpa')
{
echo "<form action='/content/822' method=post>";
echo "<input type=hidden name=filename value='$filename'>";
if($_POST['type'] == 'printprovenahpa') {echo "<input type=hidden name=isProvena      value='1'>";}
echo "<input type=hidden name=content value='";
if ($_POST['type'] == 'printphys') echo 751;
else if ($_POST['type'] == 'printprovenahpa') echo 520;
echo "'>";
echo "<input type=submit value='Start Job'></form>";
}
```

And then I get the value "isProvena" from hraprint.php and post(get) again:

```
$isProvena        = false;
extract($_REQUEST, EXTR_IF_EXISTS);
$isProvena        = (boolean)$isProvena;

<form action="/content/822" method="GET">
<input type="hidden" name="isProvena" value="<?php echo ($isProvena) ? '1' : '0' ?>" />
 <tr>
    <td><label for="showOnlyScreening">Print Only Screenings:</label></td>
    <td><input id="showOnlyScreening" type="checkbox" name="showOnlyScreening" value="1" <?php echo ($isProvena) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''?>/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
</table>
</form>
```

And post again:

```
<form action="/content/822" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="isProvena" value="<?php echo ($isProvena) ? '1' : '0' ?>" />
</table>
```

And I do the judgement here:

```
 if($isProvena){
   .........     
 }
```

The reason I need to post(get) several times is that there are several page redirect action happens in the same PHP file(hraprint.php). When I was trying to get the value which is supposed to be 'true' from if($isProvena){} and execute the function, I failed.

Anyone can help me to have a look and tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Never use `extract()` function on user-provided data. It is a really serious vulnerability.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier if you simply use sessions for that. Sessions are made specifically for that purpose - passing variables easily from one page to another.

And it is not yet established in the last code block of your answer that `$isProvena` already exists because I do not see any `extract()` there.

P.S. Use the `$_POST` and `$_GET` variables instead of extracting the `$_REQUEST`. The code is vulnerable to the problems caused by `register_globals`